# Creating an array from textarea

Tags: php, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to put some data into Amazon's simpledb.  I need to enter multiple values for an attribute (comma separated), but as I have the script now it's entering all the values as one attribute.  I think I need to create an array from the comma separated values in the textarea, but I don't know how to do that.  Heck, I don't really know how to ask this question correctly.  :)

Here's the code.

```
<?php require_once('./simpledb/config.inc.php');  ?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Input Cities</h1>
<?php
$domain = "states";
if (!empty($_POST["state"])) {  // if a value is passed from the key input field save it
$state = $_POST["state"];
} else {
$state = "";
}
$state = stripslashes($state);  // remove PHP escaping 

if (!empty($_POST["cities"])) { // if a value is passed from the key input field save it
$cities = $_POST["cities"];
} else {
$cities = "";
}
//$cities = stripslashes($cities);  // remove PHP escaping 

?>
<FORM ACTION="addcities.php" METHOD=post>

<label>State (Caps)</label><br>
<input type=text name="state" size=10 value="<?php echo $state; ?>"><br>
<label>Cities ('' & comma seperated)</label><br>
<textarea name="cities" cols=60><?php echo($cities); ?></textarea><br>
<INPUT TYPE=submit VALUE="Add Cities">


<?php

if (!class_exists('SimpleDB')) require_once('./simpledb/sdb.php');  

$sdb = new SimpleDB(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);    // create connection

$item_name = $state; 
//$input_cities = array("value" => array($cities));
echo "<p>putAttributes() item $item_name<br>"; 
//$putAttributesRequest["make"] = array("value" => "Acura"); // Example add an attribute
$putAttributesRequest['City'] = array("value" => array("Blue","Red")); // Add multiple values
```

The previous line is the manual way of adding your multiple values into the attribute.  I tried doing the following, which gets the value of the text area, but as I mentioned earlier it just creates one value that's comma seperated vs. multiple values.

`$putAttributesRequest['City'] = $input_cities; // Add multiple values`

The following is just the rest of the code.

```
$rest = $sdb->putAttributes($domain,$item_name,$putAttributesRequest);
if ($rest) {
echo("Item $item_name created");
echo("RequestId: ".$sdb->RequestId."<br>");
echo("BoxUsage: ".$sdb->BoxUsage." = " . SimpleDB::displayUsage($sdb->BoxUsage)<br>");
} else {
echo("Item $item_name FAILED<br>");
echo("ErrorCode: ".$sdb->ErrorCode."<p>");
}

?>
```

Comment: you want an array from textarea or some hints on the amazon simple-db? Can't you be more certain please?

Comment: Sorry, just hard for me to explain.  I think @Kyle R has it figured out below.

Comment: so, whole amazon thing has nothing to do with the question. Please, learn to properly split the task to independent parts. if you don't know some format required by some database - that's one question. if you know format, but have no idea how to get it - that's another. Don't mix them.

Comment: Just trying to give enough info so that someone could understand the problem I am having.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use php [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

For example:

```
$cities = explode(",", $_POST['cities']);
```

This will only work if your data is formatted like so:

> New York,Las Vegas,Sydney,Melbourne,London

Change the first part of the explode function to match the formatting of your text area.

You can then do something like:

```
foreach ($cities as $key => $val){
    echo trim($val) . '<br />';
}
```

Put your SimpleDB stuff inside the foreach loop above and use `$val` where you want to use the city name.

This will loop through the array and do the SimpleDB stuff on each city.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a go and report back.

Comment: I added your code above and I replaced this line - `$putAttributesRequest['City'] = array("value" => array("Blue","Red"));` with this `$putAttributesRequest['City'] = array("value" => array($cities));`, but the only thing added to the database is the word 'array'.

Comment: Try this. It may fix your issue: $putAttributesRequest['City'] = array("value" => $cities);

Comment: Still just entering the word 'array'.

Comment: You need to give me more information on how the SimpleDB stuff works for me to give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string on the commas.

```
$citiesArray = explode(",", $cities);
```

You'll then want to trim each of the cities to make sure there's not additional white space before or after the city name.

```
call_user_func_array("trim", $cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more Request Parameters in PUT - **Replace**. Although its default value is false, please specify it as a false. If Replace is false the value will be added as a multi-value to that attribute and if it is true then it will replace the older value.

Also you need to add single pair of 'Attribute Name and Attribute value' each time in PUT request. i.e if you need multvalue V1 & V2 of Attribute A then in you request it would be like this -

```
https://sdb.amazonaws.com/
?Action=PutAttributes
&Attribute.1.Name=A
&Attribute.1.Value=V1
&Attribute.2.Name=A
&Attribute.2.Value=V2
&Attribute.3.Replace=false
&AWSAccessKeyId=[valid access key id]
&DomainName=MyDomain
&ItemName=Item123
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&Timestamp=2010-01-25T15%3A03%3A05-07%3A00
&Version=2009-04-15
&Signature=[valid signature]
```